# pip package not available on Raspbian

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi, raspbian, pypi

When I do 'pip install demoparser2' on the Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian OS, there isnt any packages available to install, but when I do it in etc. Google Colab, then it installs a version. Is the package not compatible with RPi or whats going on here?

This is the succesful output from Google Colab.
On the RPi it just says 'No matching distribution found for demoparser2'

```
pip install demoparser2

Collecting demoparser2
  Downloading demoparser2-0.1.6-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.3 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.3/3.3 MB 49.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from demoparser2) (1.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from demoparser2) (1.23.5)
Requirement already satisfied: polars in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from demoparser2) (0.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyarrow in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from demoparser2) (9.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from demoparser2) (4.66.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pandas->demoparser2) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pandas->demoparser2) (2023.3)
Requirement already satisfied: typing_extensions>=4.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from polars->demoparser2) (4.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas->demoparser2) (1.16.0)
Installing collected packages: demoparser2
Successfully installed demoparser2-0.1.6
```

I tried installing Raspbian OS 32 and 64-bit just to see if there was a difference, but still no packages. Even tried updating python to 3.10 and pip to newest version but still no packages there. I can even pull up a terminal in Windows and install it, but not on the Pi.

There is no links on
https://www.piwheels.org/simple/demoparser2/

But there is on
https://www.pypi.org/simple/demoparser2/

Is this the problem?

Best regards

Comment: That output ends with `Successfully installed demoparser2-0.1.6`, so I don't understand what you mean when you say "there isnt any packages available to install"...

Comment: This is the succesful output from Google Colab.  On the RPi it just says 'No matching distribution found for <package>'

Comment: For goodness sake, show us the output **that actually has the problem**.  Showing us the successful output doesn't help much...

Comment: Could it have something to do with the pypi wheel on Raspbian?